# how to display value in textarea

Tags: html

I want to display the values in textarea how I am getting form server.
e.g

I am getting the 5 lines of string which also formatted with new line chars.But in firefox it wrap the values with one another.

Frequency

Comment: can you post some relevant code?

Comment: <textarea id="baseTransmitLan"  noGlyph="true" rows="3" value="Reason: Valid
 Baseline Time: Mon 2014-01-27 
 Lane 1: value1
 Lane 2: value2
 Lane 3: value3
 Lane 4: value4" height="220" width="230" >
 <label>Frequency</label>
</textarea>

Comment: are you applying any css on this textarea?

Comment: <textarea id="dispbaseReceiveLan" style="width:200px;height:160px;" o rows="3" cols="30" maxlength="" value=" Baseline Reason: LOS_CLRD
Baseline Time: Mon 2014-01-27 06:45:54 UTC RxBslPwr Lane 1 : 0.05 dBm RxBslPwr Lane 2 : -0.15 dBm RxBslPwr Lane 3 : -0.34 dBm RxBslPwr Lane 4 : -0.81 dBm RxBslPwr Lane 5 : -0.75 dBm RxBslPwr Lane 6 : -0.78 dBm RxBslPwr Lane 7 : -0.95 dBm RxBslPwr Lane 8 : -1.21 dBm RxBslPwr Lane 9 : -1.32 dBm RxBslPwr Lane 10 : -2.15 dBm " wrap="virtual">Frequency</textarea>